# Cannot enable Google Translate API

Tags: google-translate

I've created a project with a billing account. Then I navigated to the APIs page, and tried to enable the Translate API. Then I got a window about license agreement. I checked and accepted it. There was a notification "Enabling API". Then I got the window again,and again, and again... and the API is still OFF.

Why?

In my billing account I've filled all the information, there is a valid bank account number.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you were trying to activate the API from the new console interface. That is buggy and won't let you to successfully perform the activation, so you should revert to the old one (at the bottom of the screen yo might read something like "Return to original console") and it will work with no pain.